# python behaves differently when run through CMD

Tags: python-3.x

when run through CMD reading a binary file will return a string instead of a byte_array.
for example:

```
with open("Image_file", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read(1)
print(type(data))
```

will return str.
and when you run it via python IDLE it will return a bytearray.
what could be causing this?

Comment: You have python2 installed too, and you have run that from the command line.

Comment: thanks man. I was so frustrated .

Answer (score 0):

You have python2 installed too, and you have run that from the command line. Check your python installations and path conffiguration.